# How to determine whether sqlcmd has executed stored procedure successfully or not

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, stored-procedures

I have a batch file which is executing a stored procedure. The stored procedure is returning a result set as well. I am running the following sql from the batch file:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
EXEC spc.vs_load_tables
```

However the stored procedure returns 1 if it encounters error. How do I capture that here? I have used `ERRORLEVEL`. But `ERRORLEVEL` is 0 even when the stored procedure is returning an error. Please help.

Comment: Alter your stored procedure to use `RAISERROR`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = spc.vs_load_tables
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Comment: How do I use Return Value in my bat file? Sorry for asking novice questions but I have not worked in bat files before.

Comment: If you use the code above, the invocation to the SP will fill the `@return_value` variable with the return value. From there all you need to do is use the variable to do whatever suits your needs...